# how to expand variables to multiple rules in makefile?

Tags: makefile, rule

Say that I have two variables in Makefile

```
CXXFILES = a.cpp b.cpp
OBJFILES = a.o b.o
```

I would like to write a rule that will expand to

```
a.cpp : a.o
  g++ -o a.o a.cpp
b.cpp : b.o
  g++ -o b.o b.cpp
```

Note that I'm not looking for

```
%.o : %.cpp
  g++ -o $@ $<
```

because I don't want to match all .cpp files -- I only want those files specified by a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a [Static Pattern Rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

> Here is an example, which compiles each of foo.o and bar.o from the
>   corresponding .c file:
>
> ```
> objects = foo.o bar.o
>
> all: $(objects)
>
> $(objects): %.o: %.c
>     $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
> ```